# How does resource manager acquire resource in HAWQ?

Tags: resourcemanager, hawq

In HAWQ, how does resource manager acquire resource? And what kind of granularity of resource can be specific by user?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/20/resourcemgmt/HAWQResourceManagement.html) covers this pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

granularity of resource is virtual segments. There are various kinds of strategies and GUCs to control the virtual segments for different clusters and workloads. 
For details, please ref the document:
http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/20/query/query-performance.html#topic_wv3_gzc_d5

Answer (score 0):

Generally, HAWQ resource manager get resources from YARN in the hadoop cluster and organize these resources into some internal resource which serve query when needed.